# Which phones support Android Jellybean offline speech recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline

I understand that not all phones support the Android 4.1 offline speech recognition. Can anybody tell me which phones support this feature and which do not? I have seen some Samsung phones that has it, and one Chinese phone that does not (the model X720D, CPU MTK8577). What makes some phones support the feature or not? is it the CPU?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about device features and not about programming. android.stackexchange.com is a better place for Android device questions.

Answer (score 1):

Many Chinese phones don't have Google Apps installed, along with other common Android apps like the Play Store. That could be your issue.

I'm fairly certain the provider for offline speech recognition is Google Voice Search. To check if it is there or not you can type the following adb command (under linux or Mac OS):

```
 a shell pm list packages | grep com.google.android.voicesearch
```

If you get a result, Voice Search is installed, otherwise, no luck. If you can't or don't want to use adb, just look for Google Voice Search in your app manager on the phone.

It is definitely not the CPU, however.